# Hide Administrators From User List except current user (administrator)

Tags: wp-query, users, mysql

this code works great! the problem is that this code also hide the current user (if administrator) so what i trying to to do is hide all Administrators except current user.

i need help to edit sql to make this work with "$user_ID"

```
function isa_pre_user_query($user_search) {
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  //if (!current_user_can('administrator')) { // Is Not Administrator - Remove Administrator
    global $wpdb;
    $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
    $user_search->query_where = 
        str_replace('WHERE 1=1', 
            "WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.ID IN (
                 SELECT {$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
                    WHERE {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = '{$wpdb->prefix}capabilities'
                    AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value NOT LIKE '%administrator%')", 
            $user_search->query_where
        );
  //}
}
add_action('pre_user_query','isa_pre_user_query');
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the [WordPress VIP Development Best Practices](http://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/best-practices/database-queries/):

> Remember that the database is not a tool box. Although you might be
>   able to perform a lot of work on the database side, your code will
>   scale much better by keeping database queries simple and performing
>   necessary calculations and logic in PHP.

That said, you might just try to get all non-admin users and then add the current user to the results, if that user has admin capabilities.

You can easily achieve this using higher-level WordPress functions:

```
    <?php
    /* get all non-admin users */
    $args = array( 
        'meta_key'     => 'wp_capabilities', 
        'meta_value'   => 'Administrator', /* you better check for a capability, not a role */
        'meta_compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
    );
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

    /* if current user is admin, get its user object */
    $current_admin_user = current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) ? wp_get_current_user() : null;

    /* merge non-admin users with current admin-user */
    $results = $user_query->get_results();
    $results[] = $current_admin_user;

    /* update the user query */
    $user_query->__set( 'results', $results );
    $user_query->__set( 'total_users', count( $results ));

    /* do whatever you want */
    print_r($user_query);
```

Comment: Hi @Jan Beck, i try this code but i can't get it work with user list in users.php i tried to use
add_action('pre_user_query','pre_user_query'); but this not working.

Comment: so when you say users.php you mean wp-admin/users.php? Are we talking about the users admin panel where you want to hide the admins except the logged-in ones?